# Wordpress Images not displaying on Mobile

Tags: wordpress, image

Wordpress Images will display correctly on Desktop but not on Mobile. Sometimes upon refreshing, a different set of images will display each time?

I have attempting in uninstalling all plugins already, and am not sure if anyone can inspect the issue using their mobile device or offer some additional options

.htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN WP-HUMMINGBIRD-CACHING
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
<FilesMatch "\.(txt|xml|js)$">
ExpiresDefault A691200
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(css)$">
ExpiresDefault A691200
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav|mp4|m4v|ogg|webm|aac|eot|ttf|otf|woff|svg)$">
ExpiresDefault A691200
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|webp)$">
ExpiresDefault A691200
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(txt|xml|js)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=691200"
  </FilesMatch>
  <FilesMatch "\.(css)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=691200"
  </FilesMatch>
  <FilesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav|mp4|m4v|ogg|webm|aac|eot|ttf|otf|woff|svg)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=691200"
  </FilesMatch>
  <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|webp)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=691200"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# END WP-HUMMINGBIRD-CACHING
# BEGIN ShortPixelWebp

# END ShortPixelWebp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it looks like you have/had ShortPixel with WebP rewriting active, my guess would be that the WebP images have gotten stuck in an "upstream" cache. When you load the page in Chrome, Firefox, Edge (anything except Safari), cached WebP images will load just fine. But try viewing the page on an iPhone, and none of the cached WebP images will load.

An upstream cache would include anything like Cloudflare, Sucuri's CloudProxy, or even a server-side cache that doesn't support varying the content based on the Accept header (the client browser's way of signaling support for WebP images).

If you clear said cache, that should resolve things for you.

But as Neil said, that's just shooting in the dark since you didn't give us enough information.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information here. You have only given us the code for the htaccess file and you state

> and am not sure if anyone can inspect the issue using their mobile device or offer some additional options

but you have not given us any address